# Jquery, loop else for clicks other than the first

Tags: jquery, css

So I have some code, its purpose is to load a facebook like box using `.load()`.

The code works by: `Onclick` check if hidden. If not, `.load` then `.toggle`. `Onclick` again, check if the div is visible, if so, `.toggle` to hide.

Now the div is hidden it will run through the first part of the code again. I want to prevent this and just run the else function after the first click.

How could this be achieved, through a switch maybe?

```
$(".facebook-f").click(function () {
"use strict";
if ($('.facebook-content').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('.fb-loader-content').addClass('loader');
    $('.facebook-content').load("http://www.google.com", function () {
        console.log('loader will be removed');
        $('.fb-loader-content').removeClass('loader');
    });
    $('.facebook-content').toggle();
} else {
    $('.facebook-content').toggle();
}
```

});

[Here is a link to the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W7ggL/).

Comment: Just a hint - `$(".facebook-content").is(":visible")` is a much better way of checking an element's visibility :)

Comment: thanks Archer, I was originally using: if (!$(".facebook-content").is(':visible')) { I then tried :hidden. But neither seem to do the job.

Comment: out of interest Archer, why is using, is.(":visible") a better alternative than checking the css for display:none;?

Comment: using `:visible` will avoid any future problems you could run across when you (for whatever reason in the future) decide to hide the element a different way.  Basically, let jQuery worry about whether it's visible or not, as it's pretty darned good at it!  It's just a suggestion - I tend to program defensively and wouldn't be comfortable with checking a css property in such a manner.

Comment: point well taken, thanks for the explanation. Sure it will come in useful :) cheers Archer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @LowerClassOverflowian counter method and a "[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)" I managed to make something that works.

Here is the code:

button

var element = document.getElementById("facebook-f");

element.onclick = (function () {
    "use strict";

```
// init the count to 0
var count = 0;

return function(e) {
    //count
    count++;

    if (count === 1) {    // do something on first click
        $('.fb-loader-content').addClass('loader');
        $('.facebook-content').load("templates/include/scripts/facebook.php", function () {
            $('.fb-loader-content').removeClass('loader');
        });
    } 
    if (count > 1) {
        $('.facebook-content').slideToggle(200);
    }
};
```

})
    ();

cheers everyone that helped. If you have any further suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Use a counter. So after it is clicked the 1st time, it will change the counter to 2, thus causing the else condition to run from now on.

```
$(".facebook-f").click(function () {
"use strict";
var counter = 1;  // added this
if ($('.facebook-content').css('display') == 'none' && counter === 1) {  // added another condition here
    $('.fb-loader-content').addClass('loader');
    $('.facebook-content').load("http://www.google.com", function () {
        console.log('loader will be removed');
        $('.fb-loader-content').removeClass('loader');
        counter += 1; // update the counter so it changes to 2 causing the else to run the next times
    });
    $('.facebook-content').toggle();
} else {
    $('.facebook-content').toggle();
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude. It doesn't seem to be working though, console is returning "ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable counter". Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot the `var` originally, but I added it in. So it should be `var counter = 1;` , not `counter = 1`

Comment: that makes sense cheers. I have tried this but its still not opening up after the second click. Could it be the facebook content? You can see my implementation in the footer at r.adamtoms.co.uk, would really appreciate if you could take a quick look. I cant recreate the issue in js fiddle...

Comment: try `$(body).find('.facebook-content').toggle();` in the else statement or instead of body , use whatever the parent div is of .facebook-content.

Comment: Its so close, now on the second click the content briefly appears but then dispersal. I can still see it in firebug, and its set to display:block. Really have no clue whats causing it to disappear :(

Comment: @atoms Is it's parent hidden? If it's current state is display: block, then it's parent is likely hidden. When you hide an element all of its child elements get hidden with it.

Comment: the parent isnt hidden, its useful to know about the child elements getting hidden though. I have checked z-index, position, display etc. Cant see whats causing it. Would you mind looking for me please? I have been struggling with this for ages. Thinking it might be down to facebook and what ever code its pulling in.